# Measuring smallest angle between a sparse vector and 30k other predefined sparse vectors

Tags: algorithm, sorting, statistics, computer-science, knn

I have a sparse vector, say
<0,0,...,0,8,3,...>

I'd like to find the k nearest vectors from a predefined set of 30k vectors. The specific 'near' calculation I'm doing is similar to an scalar multiplication to find the angle between the vectors.

Is there a way to optimize this process (other than the naive approach of making 30k calculations and saving the top k results)? I'm interested in optimizing running time, not mem

Comment: You might be able to get some improvement if you think of it as `O(N * D)`, where N is the number of vectors and D is the dimensionality of the vectors. For some inputs it may be possible to get better results. IE: Where most (more than in this case k) of the vectors aren't anywhere close to the query one. You could also use careful approximation and/or grouping of vectors. Though even in the best case, you'd get `O(D + k)`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to precompute all the angles and store them in a lookup table (an upper-triangular matrix).  That would cost 30k * 30k / 2 = 450m.  That would be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibly related problem which is thought not to have any non-obvious speed-ups. This is the problem of finding a pair of orthogonal boolean vectors in a list of n. Under some conditions the cost may be irreducibly O(n^2) - see e.g. slide 4 of http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/conclusions-amir.pdf. If it were lower we could do SAT significantly faster than O(2^n), which is conjectured to be hard. This at least means that a lot of people have looked at this problem and not got anywhere.